# how to count the same array value from database in laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel

I use Laravel.
I saved the array to the database in the form of a string like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNdZk.jpg)

Then I want to summarize each piece of data the same. for example "Web Dev" is 5, "Android Dev" is 3.
how to do this? I have used "Has" but the method is undefined.

```
$summary = [
        'byGender'  => [
            'male'  => Member::whereGender('MALE')->count(),
            'female'=> Member::whereGender('FEMALE')->count()
        ],
        'bySkill'      => [
            'WebDev'   => Member::expertiseCategoryHas(["Web Dev"])->count(),
            'AndroidDev'   => Member::expertiseCategoryHas(["Android Dev"])->count(),
            'BackendDev'   => Member::expertiseCategoryHas(["Backend Dev"])->count()
        ]
];
```

Comment: You can use `Member::where('expertise_categories', 'like', '%Web Dev%')->count()`, but this is not the proper way, you should use [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: since the field you have declared is an array, so you can use ( Member::whereIn('expertise_categories',["Web Dev"])->count(); )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to save your data to JSON value. Then you can use whereJsonContains() to get desired result.

First, to auto convert your array to json you can do this on your Model:

**Model.php**

```
public function setExpertiseCategoriesAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attribute['expertise_categories'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

Then on Controller use *whereJsonContains()*, for example to count Web Dev:

```
Model::whereJsonContains('expertise_categories', 'Web Dev')->count();
```